# How would I get webpack or an other JS bundler to bundle files remotely hosted?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, distributed-system

I have a distributed system and all JS files are exposed through HTTP. So a normal module would look like this:

http://example.com/path/to/main.js

```
import * as core from 'http://local.example.com/path/to/core.js';
import * as redux from 'http://cdn.example.com/redux.js@version';
// code
export default {
  ...
}
```

So each import will be using either a local resource to the system or possibly remotely available resources using CDN.

Thought when I run webpack, I get this error:

trying to parse a local generated file with such content:

```
import * as main from 'http://example.com/path/to/main.js';
```

> ERROR in ./src/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'http://example.com/path/to/main.js' in '/home/.../index.js'

Is it possible to tell webpack to fetch the urls and include them inside the bundle... While packaging cdn urls isn't a big deal for now, I'd be happy if I could simply ignore the ones with a certain url.

Thought being able to bundle remote all the http:// located files would be a good start.

Also, any remote resource linking to other resources should recursively load remotely linked resources too.

Here's my current webpack config (thought nothing much to see here):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
    ]
  },
};
```

Edit: after reading a bit, I started writing a resolver but now I'm stuck again:

```
const path = require('path');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = require('url')
const fs = require('promise-fs');
const sha1 = require('sha1')

class CustomResolver {

  async download_save(request, resolveContext) {
      console.log(request, resolveContext)

      var target = url.parse(request.request)
      var response = await fetch(request.request)
      var content = await response.text()

      try {
        await fs.stat('_remote')
      } catch(exc) {
        await fs.mkdir('_remote')
      }

      var filename = `${sha1(request.request)}.js`
      var file_path = `_remote/${filename}`

      await fs.writeFile(file_path, content)

      var abs_path = path.resolve(file_path)
      var url_path = `${target.protocol}://${target.hostname}/`
      var obj = {
        path: abs_path,
        request: request.request,
        query: '',
      }

      console.log(`${request.request} saved to ${abs_path}`)

      return obj
  }

  apply(resolver) {
    var self = this
    const target = resolver.ensureHook("resolved")

    resolver.getHook("module")
      .tapAsync("FetchResolverPlugin", (request, resolveContext, callback) => {
        self.download_save(request, resolveContext)
          .then((obj) => resolver.doResolve(target, obj, resolveContext, callback))
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            callback()
          })
      })
  }
}
```

It does currently fetch urls starting with https:// but seems to be struggling to resolve urls relative to an http resource. For example

```
ERROR in _remote/88f978ae6c4a58e98a0a39996416d923ef9ca531.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/-/@pika/polyfill@v0.0.3/dist=es2017/polyfill.js' in '_remote/'
 @ _remote/88f978ae6c4a58e98a0a39996416d923ef9ca531.js 25:0-58
 @ _remote/f80b922b2dd42bdfaaba4e9f4fc3c84b9cc04fca.js
 @ ./src/index.js
```

It doesn't look like it tries to resolve relative path to already resolved files. Is there a way to tell the resolver to try to resolve everything?

Comment: Why you do not download the files with a node.js script and then bundle locally?

Comment: @quirimmo because I'd be writing my own bundler? Each resource may link to other remotely stored resources. Fetching them would mean the bundler would still fail to load the imports linking to remote resources. I'd have to manually rewrite the file to change http urls to local ones.

Comment: nope you just have to use a custom resolver, without changing your imports in the code:

Comment: @quirimmo well I guesses so, that's why I created the question. If I knew how to do that with WebPack I wouldn't ask!

Comment: @quirimmo here I started writing a resolver but it fails to resolve absolute or relative paths to http resources.

Comment: Not sure if it applies, maybe this article might help: https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/bundling-remote-scripts-with-webpack

Answer (score 0):

Main point is: **if you have CDN files - you don't need a bundler**.

They already minified and ready to use. Just import files in root of your project and call libraries globally.

Comment: Yes of course, but that's not the main goal. Bundling cdn files would be just a side-effect. But those files can be ignored.